# How do I add domain user accounts to a server programmatically, without having the user log in?

Tags: windows-server-2008

This can be done via `Netplwiz`. Is there a way to do this programatically, perhaps via Powershell? The purpose of this is to pre-stage their user profile folder so operations can be performed upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manipulating the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` registry subkeys when you use that tool. I'm not aware of any programmatic method to make modifications to the profile list. If I were in your situation I'd write up all the programmatic folder manipulation as a logon script and use a registry value to act as a "watchdog" to allow the script to run on the user's first logon, make the changes, then mark the registry so that the script doesn't execute on future logons.